# Replace hyphen with new line in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have command output passed to variable LIST, which has hyphen separated values.

```
echo "$LIST"

- @rnc/comp@1.0 - @rnc/comp@2.1 - @rnc/list@0.2 - @rnc/sell@0.17 - app@20.10
```

I would like to convert them to lines

```
* @rnc/comp@1.0
* @rnc/comp@2.1
* @rnc/list@0.2
* @rnc/sell@0.17
* app-version@20.10
```

I tired with sed, but not getting the required output.

```
COMP=$LIST | sed 's/- / \\\n* /g/'
```

output response:

`n* @rnc/comp@1.0 n* @rnc/comp@2.1 n* @rnc/list@0.2 n* @rnc/sell@0.17 n* app@20.10`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use ruby which can do all awk/grep/sed etc can do and what they cannot do. This way, you just need to carry one tool instead of multiple tools with you. In this case, you simply split and print each element:

```
ruby -ne 'a=$_.split(/\s*-\s*|\s*\n/); for i in a; print "* #{i}\n" if i != ""; end'
* @rnc/comp@1.0
* @rnc/comp@2.1
* @rnc/list@0.2
* @rnc/sell@0.17
* app@20.10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
COMP=$LIST | sed 's/- /\n/g'| sed 's/^/\* /g'
```

Comment: I needs GNU-sed and you need to get rid of the empty line. I have tested but I cannot post the formatted output.